# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException in System.Data.Entity.dll (Entity Framework)?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a `List<State>` of `State` entity objects, and each `State` object has collections of other objects, such as `Licenses`, `Taxes`, `Bonds`, etc

There's also a collection for `ExpiredObjects`, which is a list of any object which is expired and needs to be renewed. For some reason, this property is giving me a `NullReferenceException` when I try and access it for one specific state (Nevada), but I can't for the life of me figure out what is actually `null` since I don't see any `null` values anywhere.

Here's my code that throws the exception. It loops through all the states, and adds all the `ExpiredObjects` to a view-specific collection which gets displayed. My test code is still included

```
    private List<ExpiredObject> LoadAllExpiredObjects()
    {
        var list = new List<ExpiredObject>();
        foreach (var state in States)
        {
            // This tells me the state is not null, and neither is state.ExpiredObjects
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", 
                state.Name, state == null, state.ExpiredObjects == null));

            try
            {
                var x = state.ExpiredObjects;
                Debug.WriteLine(x == null);

                // Exception occurs on the "for" line on the Nevada state only
                // Contents in for loop do not execute
                foreach (var item in x)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", item));
                    list.Add(item);
                }

                // This used to be the only line of code before I started testing
                // It fails on Nevada
                //list.AddRange(state.ExpiredObjects);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The stack trace of the error is this:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.EntityKey.AddHashValue(Int32 hashCode, Object keyValue)
   at System.Data.EntityKey.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.TryGetEntityEntry(EntityKey key, EntityEntry& entry)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Merge[TEntity](IEnumerable`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean setIsLoaded)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.GetEnumerator()
   at MyNamespace.StatesViewModel.LoadAllExpiredObjects() in C:\Users\me\Desktop\MySolution\StatesViewModel.cs:line 217
```

I also get the exact same error when I select Nevada and it tries to bind a `DataGrid` to the `ExpiredObjects` collection (if I comment out that binding, the code works fine)

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: If it's only for Nevada it must be a data problem, do a thorough check in the db.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry, I wasn't sure what information was relevant. It was db-first. All objects (`State`, `License`, `Tax`, etc) have their own database table with foreign keys linking them. They also have their own Primary Key, and nothing is inherited. I'm looking into the data now - not sure why I didn't think to do that before

Comment: @HenkHolterman You're right, the problem was in the data. The procedure I had that pulled expired objects was returning a `null` value for one of the fields that was marked in EF as not null, so whenever it tried to get that object from the database, it'd throw an error. Thank you, and if you post that as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If it's only for Nevada then it must be a data problem, do a thorough check in the db.

And to summarize, the core problem was:

- It was db-first.
- ... was returning a null value for one of the fields that was marked in EF as not null

Comment: oh man, this took a while to find but it sent me in the right direction.  I had the same error, my table data was fine, but I had an entity object based on a sql view with an improper join that inserted one null record, killed the whole thing.  Thanks for the help. +1's all around.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when accidently loading a Module multiple times in a modular Architecture.

Additional, the Module(s) where using 2 copies of the same `DbContext`, trying to connect one Entity from one Context to another Entity of the other Context.

This masked the `InvalidOperationException` (cannot use an Entity in multiple Trackers), which occurs normally without the module stuff.

Took me 3 hours to solve, maybe it helps people with the same problem